# How to link_to a page and activate a tab content on that page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm trying to link from one page directly to a specific tab on another page. I can get to the other page, but can't figure out how to get to the specific tab. has anyone done this?

On my page1.html.haml, I have:

```
.content-box-header
  %li= link_to "tab1", "#tab1", :class => "default-tab"
  %li= link_to "tab2", "#tab2", :class => ""
.content-box-content
  #tab1.tab-content.default-tab
    = render :partial => 'base1_form'
  #tab2.tab-content
    = render :partial => 'base2_form'
```

If you click tab2 link on this page, then the content of tab2 will overlap content of tab1.

On my page2.html.haml, I have:

```
= link_to "link_me", some_path
```

This link displays page1.html.haml with tab1 shown. How could I make this link activate #tab2 instead?

Comment: what plugin are you using to create and manage tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put an extra parameter on the url for page1 in page2 to activate the tab2 instead of the default tab.

so in page2:

```
= link_to "link_me", some_path(:tab2 => "")
```

and in page1, you can add this on the bottom after .content-box-content div

```
- if params[:tab2]
  :javascript
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#tab2_link").click();
    });
```

and also, add that ID on your link

```
.content-box-header
  %li= link_to "tab1", "#tab1", :class => "default-tab", :id => "tab1_link"
  %li= link_to "tab2", "#tab2", :class => "", :id => "tab2_link"
```

Comment: yes, you're a genius! it works! I added a missing { in the jQuery statement above. Much Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/, it does that kind of deep linking very well.